# WordPress: do_shortcode doesn't work well

Tags: wordpress, templates, shortcode

I am working on a wordpress site, and I have downloaded a plugin called stream video player, which has a shortcode. If I put the shortcode into the content editor, it works well and it displays the video, but if, inside a template I am creating, I call it through "do_shortcode" function, it doesn't work, it just shows the text [stream bla bla]. Can anyone help me and tell me why this is happening?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that page, I will ask this question there too

Comment: Glad you found a solution; you should post it as an own answer and accept it, otherwise the question will keep being considered "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been answered with the following, and it works!

> It is not really a shortcode, it is a content filter but you can try
>   calling the plugin's function directly

```
if( function_exists('StreamVideo_Parse_content') )
{
    echo StreamVideo_Parse_content("[stream bla bla /]");
}
```